# How and where can I calculate $\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)?$

Tags: calculus, summation, logarithms, pi

We have
$$A=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)=\ln(2)$$
$$B=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)$$
Here in $A$ $+-+-$, in $B$ $++--$, so
$$B-A=\frac{1}{2}\left(\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$
and
$$AB=\ln(2)\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+\ln(2)\right)\approx\frac{\pi}{4}$$
Here $\psi^{(0)}(z)$ - digamma function.

How and where can I calculate this constant?

Comment: What is $\psi^{(0)}$?

Comment: @Netchaiev, thank you for comment! I add information about it.

Comment: $B = \frac12\log 2 + \frac{\pi}{4}$. Hint: $\tan^{-1} x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$ for $|x| < 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$B=\sum_{k\geq 0}\left[\frac{1}{4k+1}+\frac{1}{4k+2}-\frac{1}{4k+3}-\frac{1}{4k+4}\right]=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k\geq 0}x^{4k}(1+x-x^2-x^3)\,dx $$
$$ B = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x-x^2-x^3}{1-x^4}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\ln 2}{2}}.$$